# How to merge the changes in a branch to the trunk

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, subversive

I'm new in working with branches in SVN and I'm having a problem (maybe is a concept issue) I can't understand when trying to merge the changes of a branch into the trunk.

I will develop a full example in order to explain the full problem. I'm working with Eclipse/Android and Subversive:

I created a new project with the structure shown in the `Picture 1` and commit it as the **Revision #1**  to `https://mysubversionhost/Tests/SVNTests/trunk` (ignoring gen and bin folders)

**Picture 1:**

[image]

At this point the MainActivity.java is

```
package com.example.svntests;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Then I continue working in the project and update the MainActivity.java commiting it as the **Revision #2**:

```
package com.example.svntests;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        codeA();
        codeB();
        codeC();
        System.out.println("This is a bug!");
        codeA();
        codeB();
        codeC();
    }

    private void codeA() {
        // CODE A
    }

    private void codeB() {
        // CODE A
    }

    private void codeC() {
        // CODE A
    }

}
```

At this point I decide to make a release and create a tag name **Release1.0**. The SVN structure at this point is shown in the `Picture 2` (**Revision #3**)

**Picture 2:**

[image]

Then I continue working in the trunk and removing the calls to `codeA()` and adding a class OtherActivity.class in the `com.example.svntests`. Commiting the **Revision #4** MainActivity.java at this point is:

```
package com.example.svntests;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        codeB();
        codeC();
        System.out.println("This is a bug!");
        codeB();
        codeC();
    }

    private void codeB() {
        // CODE A
    }

    private void codeC() {
        // CODE A
    }

}
```

Then I detect the bug "This is a bug!" and want to patch it in production. So I switch to the tag **Release 1.0** and fix it (removing the print line and adding a class MainController.java to the same package) and commit it **Revision #5**

At this point I want to continue working with the **Revision #4** with the bug fixed. So I switch to the trunk and use the merge wizard to bring the changes from the branch to the trunk:

[image]

I was expecting to get in my working copy the classes:

```
- MainActivity.java (With conflicts)
- OtherActivity.java
- MainController.java
```

But instead I get conflicted files that were not modified. See image below

[image]

The final state after the merge is:

[image]

What do I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have some misunderstanding in SVN common (I'm too lazy to adopt some of it to Eclipse GUI)

- /tags subtree, by convention, is "write-once" - and all|each tag **must not** have history of changes *inside /tags/*. When you want to bugfix some tag, you have (in ideal world):

  - Copy tag to /branches/
  - Patch branch
  - If branch's code went to production - tag branch as new tag (`Release 1.1`, probably)
- In order to bring only bugfix changes into trunk from location-of-bugfix, you'll better merge only revisions, related to bugfix, not the whole history ("cherry-pick merge" instead of "sync merge")(choice 3 "Revisions", enter just 5 in your sample)